# How to proceed to solve this question?

Tags: clock

I was trying to solve this question but I got stuck when I tried to use AND gate with clock and some output. I want to ask whether value of rising edge of a clock is taken as 1 or value preceding it and same for falling edge does it is taken to be 0 or value preceding it while gating clocks ?

What I think rising edge=1 and falling edge=0.

Question:[image]

Also, have a look at solution provided. Is that correct ? It's not mine solution.

Solution:[image]

Ignore flip flop delays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
The solution is wrong. This is what I got. At t2, both Qb and the adjacent nand gate output go high. Qc goes High only at t3. i.e., when the nand gate's output goes low and triggers the third flip flop. At t4, you could find that the transition at below nand gate causes another falling clock edge to compliment Qc. So this would be the ideal waveform, assuming zero delays in the flip flops and gates.

Comment: Can you also upload the timing diagram for NAND gates also because I am getting lot much confused in it.                              Also, I want to ask what will the output for flip flops(D and T both initialised with 0 changing value at rising edge of clock) at clock rising edge when an input also rises high at the same with clock i.e. both(clock and input) go high at same.

Comment: In real circuits, that is an undefined/unpredictable condition cz it violates setup time. But since we are talking about ideal conditions, you can take such an input = high itself at the rising edge.

Comment: Please upload for timing diagram for NAND also. I want to check my understanding by cross-checking with it. Also, thank you for clarifying doubt.

Answer (score 3):

A clock pin marked in that fashion means a falling edge clock. That is, things change when the clock signal goes from high to low.

And no, the answer shown, which is only a start, is incorrect.

You should chart the signals including the outputs of the two NAND gates to help you not get so confused.